# Magento connect: Create extension package on windows(localhost)

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect, magento-connect-manager

I've created a module I want to upload on Magento Commerce. I've been developing said modules on Windows(WAMP). Now, when I try to use Magento Connect package manager to pack my module, I get an error that path to files are not right, ie:

```
ERR (3): Warning: md5_file(./app/code/local\frontend/base/default/layout\ No such file or directory.
```

The problem is, obviously, that windows and unix systems use different directory path delimiters, and, again, apparently, Magento is backing up only one side, unix. So, my question is: is there a way for me to use Create Package functionality in Magento installed on Windows web server, or there's not?

Answer (score 0):

First there is no directory in magento as:

```
/app/code/local\frontend/base/default/layout\
```

you are probably giving incorrect path or choosing incorrect target,

For packaging you should go to `System->Magento Connect->Package your extension`
The content section while packaging is tricky. The directory represents as below:

```
Magento Local module file – ./app/code/local
Magento Community module file – ./app/code/community
Magento Core team module file – ./app/code/core
Magento User Interface (layouts, templates) – ./app/design
Magento Global Configuration – ./app/etc
Magento PHP Library file – ./lib
Magento Locale language file – ./app/locale
Magento Media library – ./media
Magento Theme Skin (Images, CSS, JS) – ./skin
Magento Other web accessible file – ./
Magento PHPUnit test – ./tests
Magento other – ./
```

For Example if you have your module file as app/code/community/Test/Mymodule then you need to select:

```
Magento Community module file
```

in dropdown & type should be `Recursive Dir` & value should be Test & just like any other file you can add.

Comment: Not sure if you understood my question. I do know about what you wrote, but the problem is that, given I'm on Windows, when packager tries to fetch the file, url is /app/code/local\frontend/base/default/layout (note the backslash between local and frontend).

Comment: I hope for packaging extension you went to System->Magento Connect->Package extension. for windows always use "\" & for linux always use "/" See my updated answer.

Comment: So, yeah, I'm using System->Magento Connect->Package extension. And yes, I have set Magento Community module file to recursive dir, but Magento packager is complaining about individual files. Not sure why you don't understand. So, magento has preset Magento Community module file – ./app/code/community. So now, if I add the file, with just Test.xml, it will be parsed as './app/code/community' plus windows delimiter'\' then 'Test.xml', which will be './app/code/community\Test.xml', which is the problem. That path doesn't, nor it can exist.